# $.getScript from dropbox password protected javascript file

Tags: javascript, jquery, dropbox

I want to execute a  file from Dropbox.

I have a business Dropbox account and I can protect a file using a password.
I wonder if I can send the file's password in a query parameters so that I can execute the get command.

For example:

```
$.getScript('https://dl.dropbox.com/s/mlps4b84mt6f6ug/example.js');
```

the password for this file is 'test'. 
How can I access it?

Comment: You need to use a full `$.ajax` request to send authentication headers *however* that is moot because you can't access files on third party domains unless they support CORS or JSONP - which Dropbox doesn't. To achieve what you need, you'll either need to download the file and run it locally or use a server-side proxy.

Comment: Dropbox does support CORS, but we don't support sending the password in a query parameter or header. If you have control over the shared link, I'd suggest removing the password. (The link itself is already unguessable.)